# Desynchronized data between persistance cache and database. Tomcat + Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am mapping the storage of an object "Container" as follows:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name="storage", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="container"))
@Column(name="quantity")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="object_type", referencedColumnName="id")
private Map<Item,Long> storage = new TreeMap<>();
```

I open a transaction that adds items into the storage with two procedures:

1. add [A,5], [B,5], [C,5], [D,5], [E,5]
2. add [A,5], [B,5], [F,5], [G,5]

**Facts:**

a) Debugging the transaction I can see that **before commit**, the "java storage object" contains: [A,10], [B,10], [C,5], [D,5], [E,5], [F,5] and [G,5]. So the Java storage object has correct data (the sum of the items of both inserts) before commit.

b) **After commit**, database also shows the same data: [A,10], [B,10], [C,5], [D,5], [E,5], [F,5], [G,5]. So inserts were correct.

**Problem**
When I check the java storage object in other different transaction, it shows the next data: [C,5], [D,5], [E,5], [F,5], [G,5]. (A and B are missing)

It is like somehow those objects that *were in BOTH inserts* were removed from the persistance cache. They do exist in the database (database information is correct), If I reboot the app the storage java object will show the correct data.

Any idea why the persistance cache gets this corrupted data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you load the object in the other transaction, what type of map `Fleet.storage` is? Also, how is `equals/hashCode` implemented for `ObjectType`?

Comment: Object type has an id field, and equals and hashcode is implemented using this field.

Fleet.storage is a map Map<ObjectType,Long>. So for example you could insert objects like this -> storage.put(Object_A, 5), storage.put(Object_B, 10)

Comment: I was asking what **concrete** map implementation `Fleet.storage` was when returned by Eclipselink in the other transaction

Comment: Also, when you say the first transaction makes two changes, do you mean you first insert keys A, B, C, D, E into the map, then insert A, B, F, G into the map (re-inserting A and B), and then the transaction commits? Are all 7 `ObjectType`s preexisting entities? And how are you verifying the map contents in the other transaction? Using `Map.entries()/Map.keys()`?

Comment: I updated my question to make it cleares. The anwser to your question is yes, I add the items A and B twice, storage shows the sum correctly before commit.

All items are prexisting entities @ReadOnly.

To check the data information I just check the content of collection "storage" (Map<Item,Long>)

Comment: What options are you using for the shared cache, and how and when are you reading in this entity in relation to these transactions? You might try a em.refresh on it to see if that forces a correction.